# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии ссылки выбирался определенный option из списка?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку  `Siegen` выбирался из списка регион (например `Nordrhein-Westfalen`) и дополнительно  добавлялось в текстовое поле `Siegen`

Вот код, который  есть и который я немного дополнил  сам:

```
<div class="row ui-row-text">
            <label for="regionId"><?php _e('Земля', 'brasil'); ?> *</label>
           <?php ItemForm::region_select(osc_get_regions(osc_user_country()), osc_user()) ; ?> - Выберите землю Германии из предложенного списка
        </div>
        <div class="row ui-row-text">
     <div class="row ui-row-text">
            <label for="city"><?php _e('City', 'brasil'); ?> *</label>
            <?php ItemForm::city_text(osc_get_cities(osc_user_region()), osc_user()) ; ?> - Начните вводить город <b>немецкими буквами</b> и выберите его из предложенных вариантов.

            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('city').value='Siegen'; document.getElementById('regionId').value='781258';">Siegen</a>
        </div>
```

Город вставляется уже в текстовое поле, но регион не получается добавить, вернее он не обновляется при нажатии на ссылку. Когда хочешь выбрать регион, то тогда только регион отмечается нужный.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста воздержитесь от излишних приветствий и просьб о помощи, они лишь усложняют чтение вопроса и отвлекают от сути проблемы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**на Jquery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".SiegenButton").click(function() {
      $("#city").val("Siegen");
      $("#regionId option[value='781258']").attr("selected", "selected");
    });
  });
</script>


<div class="row ui-row-text">
  <label for="regionId">
    <?php _e( 'Земля', 'brasil'); ?>*</label>
  <?php ItemForm::region_select(osc_get_regions(osc_user_country()), osc_user()) ; ?>- Выберите землю Германии из предложенного списка
</div>
<div class="row ui-row-text">
  <div class="row ui-row-text">
    <label for="city">
      <?php _e( 'City', 'brasil'); ?>*</label>
    <?php ItemForm::city_text(osc_get_cities(osc_user_region()), osc_user()) ; ?>- Начните вводить город <b>немецкими буквами</b> и выберите его из предложенных вариантов.

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="SiegenButton">Siegen</a>
  </div>
```

**на javascript**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SiegenButton()">Siegen</a>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function SiegenButton() {
         document.getElementById('city').value='Siegen';
         document.getElementById("regionId").value = "781258";
         //или
         //document.getElementById("regionId").selectedIndex = 0;
      }
  </script>
```

P.S.: в случае проблемы выложите код ваших селектов, т.к. бывают селекты со своими js(в большинстве случаев у таких селектов свой обработчик).

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось просто, поправив шаблон стилей css, заработал следующий код:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('city').value='Berlin'; document.getElementById('regionId').value='781251';">Berlin</a>
```

Спасибо Alex за помощь!